# Why doesn't my static library define all the functions defined in its source code?

Tags: c, bash, shell, gcc, makefile

i'm trying to create a simple makefile after a long period without coding in C but i'm stuck.

Once compiled i can only access the first function (here ft_isalpha) but i don't know why.

here is the makefile:

```
  1 SRC =           ft_isalpha.c \                                                                                                                        
  2                 ft_strlen.c
  3 
  4 SRC_DIR =       src/
  5 
  6 SRC_PREFIXED =  $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR), $(SRC))
  7 
  8 NAME =          libft.a
  9 
 10 OBJS_DIR =      objs/
 11 
 12 OBJS =          $(SRC:.c=.o)
 13 
 14 OBJS_PREFIXED = $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR), $(OBJS))
 15 
 16 CC =            gcc
 17 
 18 FLAGS =         -Wall -Wextra -Werror
 19 
 20 
 21 $(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_PREFIXED)
 22     @mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)
 23     gcc $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@
 24 
 25 $(NAME): $(OBJS_PREFIXED)
 26     ar r $(NAME) $(OBJS_PREFIXED)
 27     @echo $(SRC_PREFIXED)
 28 
 29 all: $(NAME)
 30 
 31 
 32 clean:
 33     @rm -rf $(OBJS_DIR)
 34     @echo "objects directory deleted"
 35 
 36 fclean: clean
 37     @rm -rf $(NAME)
 38     @echo ".a file deleted"
```

i've check the content of variables and command lines that are generating with those variables but everything looks fine. When i switch ft_isalpha and ft_strlen, ft_strlen is accessible and not isalpha ad so on.

Comment: A good place to start would be to read the log that `make` runs when it's being executed, and compare those commands to what you expect and intend them to contain. In particular, what arguments are passed to `ar` as it's actually invoked?

Comment: Run `make fclean`. Then run `make all`. [Edit] your question to copy-paste (as text) the full and complete output from the `make all` command.

Comment: Note that nobody but you has `ft_isalpha.c` or `ft_strlen.c`, so _we can't run your makefile_ to see the problem ourselves or test our answers; it's certainly possible to make some educated guesses, but ideally, we want questions that allow provably-correct answers.

Comment: Also, "undefined references" is an error you typically get when creating an application, not a library. Please [edit] your question to give us more context. And, as I mentioned before, the full and complete build output (so we can see the actual errors you get).

Comment: Undefined reference to _what_? Imagine you want to travel across the country, so you call up a travel agent and say _"I want to travel to!"_ -- do you think that travel agent is going to get you where you need to go?

Comment: Please [edit] to remove the line numbers. We want code we can copy/paste and run without additional hindrances.

Comment: You only show the makefile, but not the output you get when running the file. If you suspect that the problem lies in the list on the variable `SRC`, I would first put both files into the same line instead of using a continuation line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is...

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_PREFIXED)    # ... <- here (A)
    @mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)
    gcc $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@        # ... <- and here (B)
```

The pattern rule (A) says that *each* object file `objs/(ft_isalpha.o|ft_strlen.o)`
depends on *all* the source files `src/ft_isalpha.c`, `src/ft_strlen.c`. Of
course that is false.

Then the command (B) means that each target object file `$@` is to be made by
compiling the source file `$<`. Per the
[GNU Make manual: 10.5.3 Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables),
`$<` means:

> $<
>
> The name of the first prerequisite. ...[cut]...

So each target object file `objs/(ft_isalpha.o|ft_strlen.o)` is made by compiling
*the same* source file `src/ft_isalpha.c`.

Thus you create a library `libft.a` that contains two object files `ft_isalpha.o`,`ft_strlen.o`
both of which define the same function `ft_isalpha` and neither of which defines `ft_strlen`.

Your linkage then fails with an undefined reference to `ft_strlen`. Your linkage does *not* yield
a multiple definition error for `ft_isalpha` because the the linker satified your program's reference to
`ft_isalpha` by extracting and linking `libft.a(ft_isalpha.o)` and had then no reason to link `libft.a(ft_strlen.o)`: no further unresolved symbols are defined in the library.

When your reverse the order of `ft_isalpha.c` and `ft_strlen.c`, the opposite thing happens, as you
observed - because all of the object files are now compiled from `ft_strlen.c`.

To correct this particular mistake, change:

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_PREFIXED)
```

to:

```
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRC_DIR)%.c
```

That makes each object file depend only on the *corresponding* source file; the first prerequisite `$<`
becomes the *only* prerequisite and each object file will be compiled from the correct source.

Comment: If you read carefully the output of make, you will notice that it was compiling the same source file twice, but putting the output in different object files.  This is one of the best ways to debug a makefile.

Comment: (...and it's why I asked, yesterday, that the question be edited to add the output of actually _running_ the makefile)